# Lego EV3 <-> Wolfram Language

Tags: hardware, input-devices

Does anyone know a source for a tutorial how to control a LEGO EV3 with WL?

Thank you,

JJJ

Comment: Seems like this is the most productive strategy;
http://www.ev3dev.org/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I was looking for, because you have to change the firmware of the EV3.

Comment: I realize that Mindstorms is attractive in its simplicity, but why not use a Pi? There is a free Mathematica distro for it.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime I was able to set up a connection between WL/MMA and my EV3. It was (at the end) very simple, but since I don't know anything about Serial Communications I had to figure out a few things.

In fact, only one line was necessary to set up the connection:

```
dev = DeviceOpen["Serial", "/dev/tty.EV3-SerialPort"]
```

I will report later on on further steps. Currently I'm trying to read the device...

JJJ

Comment: As I reported before, I'm able to establish communications between EV3 and WL/MMA. But now, the DeviceRead[dev] always reports a $TimedOut instead of some date (I know that data is streamed down from the EV3, because I can see it in the MindStorms Home Edition software).

Comment: Of course, if you just want to talk to Mathematica remotely I believe mindstorms supports bluetooth. The rest is basic comms protocol stuff.

Comment: I would still give a good long think to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Yes, that's true, it's serial communication stuff, but if you don't have any idea (like me), this is an issue... And yes, I will consider Rasp Pi.

Comment: that's why I keep harping on Pi. Running an instance natively is guaranteed to be faster than a remote connection, and in robotics speed is at a premium

Comment: how'd you make out?

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Mindstorms many moons ago. Their (IMO very stupid) stock IDE is based on [NI Labquest](http://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/labview.html), which I find to be an unmitigated disaster in the vein of many attempts to give programming abilities to people whose eyes glaze over at the sight of code. If you don't want to replace stock firmware, I think your best strategy is to try to repurpose anything you find that will connect Wolfram to Labview. Sadly, [Wolfram's official package](https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/labview/) is proprietary and closed-source. Shocking, I know.

Comment: I had occasion to "play" with Mindstorms around the time it was first launched (late 90's, IIRC). Coming from a command-line background, I thought the "block-style" programming was cute at best, and counterproductive to learning at worst.

Comment: @J.M. I com from computer music land. They've had things there for a long time like Max/MSP, Processing, and Reaktor, that all still drag themselves over the landscape like pathetic rotting zombies because scary coding is scary. The resulting boggles must be seen to be believed.

Comment: This answer is rather opinion-based, irrelevant and its only link is dead. It neither provides a solution nor a pointer to a tutorial OP asked for. Furthermore, it refers to a "strategy" which is far from triviial but fails to deliver any specifics.